# Недостаточно памяти для выполнения скрипта Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

столкнулся с такой ошибкой, при входе в редактирование страницы на Wordpress.

`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 129236992) (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /app/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2516`

Страница запилена через метабоксы с помощью плагина ACF (Advanced custom fields) Не могу сказать, что там очень много полей, от чего бы php в обморок падал, но и  не мало.

Во всяком случае на локальной машине такой ошибки нет. 
В настройках сервера лимит памяти установен в размере 256 мб. `memory_limit 256MB`

И вот значение `(allocated 129236992)` скачет от 50 мбайт до 150 мбайт. Обрывается всегда в файле `wp-db.php` или `meta.php`

Я думаю на хостинге темнят, мне кажется они выделяют не ровно 256 мб, а до 256 мб и временами эта отметка падает очень низко.

Кто может подсказать с чем может быть связана проблема?

Comment: Ну что тут сказать. Вы сами все выводы сделали. Меняйте хостинг.

Comment: А Вы как считаете? )

Comment: Ну раз на локалке ок, а на хостинге нет - значит, плохой хостинг